# PHP PDO statement will NOT submit information to database

Tags: php, sql, pdo, insert

I have literally been working on this for hours. And I have absolutely 0 clue why it will not send my information to my database... I have used the same tactic before and it has worked brilliantly. Now it will not INSERT no matter what. Please help!

```
if ($validForm) {

    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO credentials (firstname, lastname, username, password) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :username, :password)');
        $stmt->bindValue(':fname',$firstname);
        $stmt->bindValue(':lname',$lastname);
        $stmt->bindValue(':username',$username);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password',$password);
        $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
        $stmt->bindValue(':password',$passwordHash);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

<p class="success-message">Thank You. Your Form Has Been Submitted.</p>

<?php
}
```

[image]

Comment: $stmt->bindValue(':password',$password); -- You have used it 2 times.

Comment: Aniother one: $stmt->bindValue(':password',$passwordHash);

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Show database structure and error please

Comment: There is no error that's the issue

Comment: write ini_set('display_errors',1) on the top of your code

Comment: "Still not working" after you did _what_ exactly?

Comment: I added an image of the sql database

Comment: There is not any Auto Increment for user_id :(. And may be you are sending null values but database field parametr is not null. You should check error, otherwise it will be difficult to solve problem

Comment: I added the piece of code you gave me that is supposed to display errors but nothing is happening ... and I do have an auto increment set for that field.

Comment: may be your form is not valid ?

Comment: I have set up a ton of validation in order to make sure all fields are valid...

Comment: Ok, just for checking write echo 1; die; after if ($validForm) { , and see if it shows 1.

Comment: And would be good if you show us your table structure

Comment: Is PDO set to throw exceptions? ie, do you have `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`?

Answer (score 1):

What datatype, collation and length is your password column set to?

In your screenshot all the passwords are short text strings, but if I apply your hash code to the first password the result is:

`$2y$12$S7tIbSxqNNhn/Z7AyA8ewuq09IE/psFyVL5udLUNgmP4Q7vTd/qFO`

Is your table going to accept that?

Comment: This would make an excellent comment but isn't really an answer (well, yet anyway)

Comment: Guys, I got it working! I was curious about how password hashing works... Like it registers it into the database but how does it work when you actually try to login using the login page? Like how does it read the actual password? I'm very new to PHP haha...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should one of these:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':password',$passwordHash);
```

Or

```
$stmt->bindValue(':password',$password);
```